# NOAA XML Parsing in Java - getting the latitude and longitude element

Tags: java, xml

I am trying to parse this particular latitude and longitude string into my XML Parser written in Java, but I am not sure what element to use, as point does not having a closing `/>`

```
<data>
<location>
<location-key>point1</location-key>
<point latitude="39.95" longitude="-75.17"/>
</location>
<moreWeatherInformation applicable-location="point1">
http://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?textField1=39.95&textField2=-75.17
</moreWeatherInformation>
<time-layout time-coordinate="local" summarization="none">
<layout-key>k-p24h-n1-1</layout-key>
<start-valid-time>2013-10-30T08:00:00-04:00</start-valid-time>
<end-valid-time>2013-10-30T20:00:00-04:00</end-valid-time>
</time-layout>
<time-layout time-coordinate="local" summarization="none">
<layout-key>k-p24h-n2-2</layout-key>
<start-valid-time>2013-10-29T20:00:00-04:00</start-valid-time>
<end-valid-time>2013-10-30T09:00:00-04:00</end-valid-time>
<start-valid-time>2013-10-30T20:00:00-04:00</start-valid-time>
<end-valid-time>2013-10-31T09:00:00-04:00</end-valid-time>
</time-layout>
<parameters applicable-location="point1">
<temperature type="maximum" units="Fahrenheit" time-layout="k-p24h-n1-1">
<name>Daily Maximum Temperature</name>
<value>64</value>
</temperature>
<temperature type="minimum" units="Fahrenheit" time-layout="k-p24h-n2-2">
<name>Daily Minimum Temperature</name>
<value>44</value>
<value>52</value>
</temperature>
</parameters>
</data>
```

Using the code below, I get the following output.

```
try {
            File newXMLFile = new File("H:\\520\\SOAP Data Acquisition\\testNOAA.xml");
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = dBuilder.parse(newXMLFile);

            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            System.out.println("Title: " + doc.getElementsByTagName("title").item(0).getTextContent());
            System.out.println("Field: " + doc.getElementsByTagName("field").item(0).getTextContent());
            System.out.println("category: " + doc.getElementsByTagName("category").item(0).getTextContent());
            System.out.println("Date Created: " + doc.getElementsByTagName("creation-date").item(0).getTextContent());

            NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("data");

            for(int i = 0; i < nList.getLength(); i++){
                Node nNode = nList.item(i);
                System.out.println("\nCurrent Element: " + nNode.getNodeName());
                if(nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE){
                    Element eElement = (Element) nNode;

                    System.out.println("Location: " + eElement.getAttribute("point"));
                    System.out.println("Start Time: "+eElement.getElementsByTagName("start-valid-time").item(0).getTextContent());
                    System.out.println("End Time: "+eElement.getElementsByTagName("end-valid-time").item(0).getTextContent());

                    System.out.println("");
                }
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Output:

```
Title: NOAA's National Weather Service Forecast Data
Field: meteorological
category: forecast
Date Created: 2013-10-29T14:42:58Z

Current Element: data
Location: 
Start Time: 2013-10-30T08:00:00-04:00
End Time: 2013-10-30T20:00:00-04:00
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not having a closing /"? I see it right there. You need to get the value of attributes, not element.
You probably want to do something like this:
    ```eElement.getElementsByTagName("point").getAttribute("latitude")```

Comment: Do you mean by using `.getAttribute()` instead of `.getElement()`?

Comment: That does not work. The error I get with that is `cannot find symbol`

Comment: Your example is not complete and there is a lot of irrelevant stuff. Is the start time and end time under the same element as location? If yes, then I don't see any reason why it shouldn't work. But I guess it's somewhere else.

Comment: I didn't want to past too much XML code into the example, but I will update it.

Comment: Ok. Then I guess this will work:
```eElement.getElementsByTagName("location").getElementsByTagName("point").getAttribute("latitude")```

Comment: http://puu.sh/52XTT/41d532925c.png `Cannot find symbol` error =/

Comment: You're getting that error because the result of `getElementsByTagName` is a `NodeList` and `NodeList` does not itself have a method called `getElementsByTagName`. You have to get the first element of the list and then ask it. **Or** you can skip that, if there's only going to be one `point`; see my answer below.

Comment: ah.. sorry. getElementsByTagName returns Nodelist, not Node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the relevant part of your code try this instead. It's assuming there's only going to be one "point" in the entire "data" tag (or at least, that you're only interested in the first "point"), but it works *for what you have posted*.

```
        NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("data");

        for(int i = 0; i < nList.getLength(); i++){
            Node nNode = nList.item(i);
            System.out.println("\nCurrent Element: " + nNode.getNodeName());
            if(nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE){
                Element eElement = (Element) nNode;

                Element point = (Element)(eElement.getElementsByTagName("point").item(0));
                System.out.println("Location: " + point.getAttribute("latitude") + ", " + point.getAttribute("longitude"));
                System.out.println("Start Time: "+eElement.getElementsByTagName("start-valid-time").item(0).getTextContent());
                System.out.println("End Time: "+eElement.getElementsByTagName("end-valid-time").item(0).getTextContent());

                System.out.println("");
            }
        }
```

Comment: That worked - thank you so much. If I am understanding this correctly - you are casting `eElement.getElementsByTagName("point").item(0)` into an element, and using the `element` methods such as `getAttribute()`?

Comment: Exactly. Like you have at the top where you are getting the `data` tag, the result of `getElementsByTagName` is a `NodeList`. So I pull the first item of the `NodeList`, cast it to an `Element` and get the longitude and latitude from that (since they are defined as attributes on that element). The result of `getAttribute()` is a `String` so if you want them as `float`s or `double`s you'll have to parse...

Comment: It's also worth noting, in case it wasn't obvious, that `getElementsByTagName` does a deep search. It doesn't just return direct children by that name, but any `Element` that is nested, however deep, inside the `Element` you are making that call on.

Comment: Is there any way to see what `type` an object and method is and returns, respectively?

Comment: Most IDEs should provide that information to you; it's also in the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Element.html#getElementsByTagName%28java.lang.String%29).